# While redirect using .htaccess, images are not display properly

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am new to rewrite url. While redirecting, some of the images are not visible.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ product_details.php?pid=$1&cid=$2&subject=$3&manname=$4&modelname=$5&proname=$6 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ brand_view.php?cid=$1&brandid=$2&Start=$3&getbrandname=$4&subbname=$5 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ brand_list.php?brandname=$1&Start=$2&subject=$3&getbrandname=$4 [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if they are by direct or by relative path. Maybe thats the problem.

Comment: i use a base url like this <base href="http://example.co.uk/" /> inside a head tag

Comment: base is for redirect. The problem might be within the href instead. Are there any difference between the non-workings and working ones. (Maybe a couple of slashes in front of).

Comment: i use a href link like this <a href="35/4/0/BOSE/SoundDock">bose</a>

Comment: while writing a first two rewrite url, i didnt get any problem, while writing a third one only i get a problem on image.whether due to this [L]

Comment: Can you try using ABSOLUTE urls for your images source. http://www.motive.co.nz/glossary/linking.php If using them the images display. Then that's the problem.

Comment: Look also the page source. Maybe with the redirects one more .(dot) is being wrote as prefix of the source.

Comment: thank you friends, i got a solution.i use a image manipulation like thumb.php?file=images/get/new.jpg&width=100&heigth=100 in all the page.i forgot to give one page, so i rewrite in that pages,images are not displaying.